# Converting the time format from $7. to time5. in sas

Tags: sas

I have a sas dataset with a column called "time" in the format of $7., such as 23:57.

I tried to covert it into the format of time5. as below, but it returned errors as "invalid numeric data...".

```
data want;
set have;
time1 = input(time, time5.);
format time1 time5. 
run;
```

So I'd like to know what is the right code. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in your `format` statement, but your code is correct. Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work.  Note if you want times before 10AM to print with a leading zero and none of the times are larger than 24 hours then use TOD5. instead of TIME5. in the format statement.  Also try reading all 7 bytes of the original string variable instead of just the first 5.

```
data want;
  set have;
  time1 = input(time, time7.);
  format time1 tod5. ;
run;
```

To see if it worked compare the original variable to the new one.

```
proc freq data=want;
  tables time1*time / list missing;
run;
```